# Cordova In-App Camera

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

How would I go about creating an in-app camera for a cordova (v3.4) application? By that I mean a custom skin, not just using `.getPicture` to jump you into the device camera. Is this even possible?

Edit: A little digging has led me to a ton of excitement about `getUserMedia()`, but while this works in Chrome on Android, it doesn't seem to work on iOS, and isn't supported through [Googles cca toolkit](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps).

I also found tutorials for iOS like [this one](http://codrspace.com/vote539/writing-a-custom-camera-plugin-for-phonegap/), which implements a custom iOS camera as a plugin.

Are there existing plugins that will work on at least Android and iOS that allow a custom skin on a camera? Or do I really have to write my own?

Comment: did you achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can start from my Wezka Native Camera
https://github.com/shaithana/cordova-plugin-wezka-nativecamera and fork if you want.